# Using Spring MVC Test to unit test multipart POST request

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I have the following request handler for saving autos. I have verified that this works when I use e.g. cURL. Now I want to unit test the method with Spring MVC Test. I have tried to use the fileUploader, but I am not managing to get it working. Nor do I manage to add the JSON part.

How would I unit test this method with Spring MVC Test? I am not able to find any examples on this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "autos", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity saveAuto(
    @RequestPart(value = "data") autoResource,
    @RequestParam(value = "files[]", required = false) List<MultipartFile> files) {
    // ...
}
```

I want to uplod a JSON representation for my auto + one or more files.

**I will add 100 in bounty to the correct answer!**

Answer (score 343, accepted):

Since `MockMvcRequestBuilders#fileUpload` is deprecated, you'll want to use [`MockMvcRequestBuilders#multipart(String, Object...)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMvcRequestBuilders.html#multipart-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) which returns a [`MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder.html). Then chain a bunch of [`file(MockMultipartFile)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/request/MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder.html#file-org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile-) calls.

Here's a working example. Given a `@Controller`

```
@Controller
public class NewController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String saveAuto(
            @RequestPart(value = "json") JsonPojo pojo,
            @RequestParam(value = "some-random") String random,
            @RequestParam(value = "data", required = false) List<MultipartFile> files) {
        System.out.println(random);
        System.out.println(pojo.getJson());
        for (MultipartFile file : files) {
            System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename());
        }
        return "success";
    }

    static class JsonPojo {
        private String json;

        public String getJson() {
            return json;
        }

        public void setJson(String json) {
            this.json = json;
        }

    }
}
```

and a unit test

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebConfig.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class Example {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        MockMultipartFile firstFile = new MockMultipartFile("data", "filename.txt", "text/plain", "some xml".getBytes());
        MockMultipartFile secondFile = new MockMultipartFile("data", "other-file-name.data", "text/plain", "some other type".getBytes());
        MockMultipartFile jsonFile = new MockMultipartFile("json", "", "application/json", "{\"json\": \"someValue\"}".getBytes());

        MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/upload")
                        .file(firstFile)
                        .file(secondFile)
                        .file(jsonFile)
                        .param("some-random", "4"))
                    .andExpect(status().is(200))
                    .andExpect(content().string("success"));
    }
}
```

And the `@Configuration` class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "test.controllers" })
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        return multipartResolver;
    }
}
```

The test should pass and give you output of

```
4 // from param
someValue // from json file
filename.txt // from first file
other-file-name.data // from second file
```

The thing to note is that you are sending the JSON just like any other multipart file, except with a different content type.

Comment: Very nice! For me it was crucial to understand that the answer also shows that the mapping works a bit differently for .file and .param. With .file, the Strings "data" and "json" from inside the 3 test files, are used to map to @RequestPart(value = "json") or @RequestParam(value = "data"). In .param("some-random", "4"), "some-random" maps the String "4" to @RequestParam(value = "some-random").

Answer (score 27):

The method `MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload` is deprecated use `MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart` instead.

This is an example:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;


/**
 * Unit test New Controller.
 *
 */
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(NewController.class)
public class NewControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext wContext;

    @MockBean
    private NewController newController;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wContext)
                   .alwaysDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                   .build();
    }

   @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
       // Mock Request
        MockMultipartFile jsonFile = new MockMultipartFile("test.json", "", "application/json", "{\"key1\": \"value1\"}".getBytes());

        // Mock Response
        NewControllerResponseDto response = new NewControllerDto();
        Mockito.when(newController.postV1(Mockito.any(Integer.class), Mockito.any(MultipartFile.class))).thenReturn(response);

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/fileUpload")
                .file("file", jsonFile.getBytes())
                .characterEncoding("UTF-8"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 19):

Have a look at this example taken from the spring MVC showcase, this is the link to the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/fileupload/FileUploadControllerTests.java):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class FileUploadControllerTests extends AbstractContextControllerTests {

    @Test
    public void readString() throws Exception {

        MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file", "orig", null, "bar".getBytes());

        webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build()
            .perform(fileUpload("/fileupload").file(file))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("message", "File 'orig' uploaded successfully"));
    }

}
```

Comment: `fileUpload` is deprecated in favor of `multipart(String, Object...)`.

Answer (score 17):

Here's what worked for me, here I'm attaching a file to my EmailController under test. Also take a look at the postman screenshot on how I'm posting the data.

```
    @WebAppConfiguration
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @SpringBootTest(
            classes = EmailControllerBootApplication.class
        )
    public class SendEmailTest {
    
        @Autowired
        private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
        
        @Test
        public void testSend() throws Exception{
            String jsonStr = "{\"to\": [\"email.address@domain.com\"],\"subject\": "
                    + "\"CDM - Spring Boot email service with attachment\","
                    + "\"body\": \"Email body will contain  test results, with screenshot\"}";
            
            Resource fileResource = new ClassPathResource(
                    "screen-shots/HomePage-attachment.png");
  
            assertNotNull(fileResource);

            MockMultipartFile firstFile = new MockMultipartFile( 
                       "attachments",fileResource.getFilename(),
                        MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
                        fileResource.getInputStream());  
            
            assertNotNull(firstFile); 
        
            MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.
                  webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
                  
            mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                   .multipart("/api/v1/email/send")
                    .file(firstFile)
                    .param("data", jsonStr))
                    .andExpect(status().is(200));
            }
        }
```

[image: Postman Request]

Comment: For me .param("data", jsonStr)
is writing out json array in the output rather than an object.

Comment: This is due to LinkedMultiValueMap internally.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Spring4/SpringBoot 1.x, then it's worth mentioning that you can add "text" (json) parts as well . This can be done via MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload().file(MockMultipartFile file) (which is needed as method `.multipart()` is not available in this version):

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {

   mockMvc.perform( 
       MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/files")
         // file-part
         .file(makeMultipartFile( "file-part" "some/path/to/file.bin", "application/octet-stream"))
        // text part
         .file(makeMultipartTextPart("json-part", "{ \"foo\" : \"bar\" }", "application/json"))
       .andExpect(status().isOk())));

   }

   private MockMultipartFile(String requestPartName, String filename, 
       String contentType, String pathOnClassPath) {

       return new MockMultipartFile(requestPartName, filename, 
          contentType, readResourceFile(pathOnClasspath);
   }

   // make text-part using MockMultipartFile
   private MockMultipartFile makeMultipartTextPart(String requestPartName, 
       String value, String contentType) throws Exception {

       return new MockMultipartFile(requestPartName, "", contentType,
               value.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));   
   }


   private byte[] readResourceFile(String pathOnClassPath) throws Exception {
      return Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
         .getResource(pathOnClassPath).toUri()));
   }

}
```