# Curl / Spring MVC : POST gives MissingServletRequestParameterException

Tags: spring-mvc, post, curl, file-upload, multipartform-data

I'm using `Spring MVC` 4 with `@RestController` to receive a form post. 
I've made it following the tips given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800726/using-spring-mvc-test-to-unit-test-multipart-post-request) and its works well with `Spring Test` `MockMvc`.

However, I'd like now to POST things to my server with `curl`, and I don't find a way to be accepted. I always get the following exception :
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'file' is not present

I've tried to mix with the `@Consumes` from `Spring` and the `-H` option from `curl`, but it doesn't seem to be relevant.

So, given the following `@RestController`, what `curl` command should be executed to post something ?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = ONE_COLLECTION)
public class OneCollectionController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public RESTDocumentListElement uploadDocument( @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("data") NewDocumentData documentData ) throws IOException {
       // -- code here --
    }
}
```

The last command I've tried (and got exception):

```
curl http://host/oneCollection -X POST -F "file=@./myFile.txt" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F 'data={"name"="myName"}'
```

The working `Spring Test` `MockMvc` code:

```
// ...

MockMultipartFile firstFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", "dummyFile.txt", "text/plain", "blahblah".getBytes());
MockMultipartFile jsonFile = new MockMultipartFile("data", "", "application/json", TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonString(documentData).getBytes() );

ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(fileUpload(ONE_COLLECTION)
                    .file(firstFile)
                    .file(jsonFile)
    );

// ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out !

I've changed the controller method mapping for:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"multipart/*"})
 public RESTDocumentListElement uploadDocument( @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("data") NewDocumentData documentData ) throws IOException {
```

But the tricky part was for the `MultipartResolver` in my JavaConfig, I was using the standard `StandardServletMultipartResolver` provided by Servlet 3, and had to switch to the Apache Commons one:

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

so I needed to had some dependency in maven too

```
<!-- Apache Commons -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

and finally, the curl command was:

```
curl http://host/oneCollection -X POST -F 'file=@./firstFile.txt;type=text/plain' -F 'data={"collection":"toto"};type=application/json' -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
```