# MockMVC | Need to pass JSON file as input

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

I would like to pass an input file to MockMVC perform statement. Please find the code snippet below:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {

   this.mockMvc.perform(post("/tax_rates/v1/quotations")
           .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).pathInfo("/src/main/resources/input.json"))
           .andExpect((ResultMatcher) status().is2xxSuccessful());

}
```

When I tried using pathInfo variable I get the error as below:

> HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing:

which i guess it means payload is not getting passed?

Any suggestions would help me.

Regards,
Sunil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can pass json input as content :

```
ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
String jsonString=mapperwriteValueAsString(mapper.readValue(new File("path/to/file",Object.class));
 this.mockMvc.perform(post("/tax_rates/v1/quotations")
           .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).content(jsonString))
           .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
```

If you want to pass MultipartFile as input. Here is the link:

[Using Spring MVC Test to unit test multipart POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800726/using-spring-mvc-test-to-unit-test-multipart-post-request)