# Sending an object with files using the MockMvc test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, testing, mockmvc

I want to send an object to the controller that has several lists with files and several fields with plain text.

```
public class ContributionNew<T extends MovieInfoDTO> {
    private List<T> elementsToAdd;
    private Map<Long, T> elementsToUpdate;
    private Set<Long> idsToDelete;
    private Set<String> sources;
    private String comment;
}

public class Photo extends MovieInfoDTO {
    private MultipartFile photo;
}

@PostMapping(value = "/{id}/contributions/photos")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public
ResponseEntity<Void> createPhotoContribution(
        @ApiParam(value = "The movie ID", required = true)
        @PathVariable("id") final Long id,
        @ApiParam(value = "The contribution", required = true)
        @RequestBody @Valid final ContributionNew<Photo> contribution
) {
```

I want to create a test to send an object, but I do not know how to finish it.

```
@Test
public void testCreatePhotoContribution() throws Exception {
    ContributionNew<Photo> contribution = new ContributionNew<>();
    MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("photo", "C:\\Users\\Jonatan\\Pictures\\2.png",
            "image/png", "Spring Framework".getBytes());
    Photo.Builder photoBuilder = new Photo.Builder(
            multipartFile
    );
    contribution.getElementsToAdd().add(photoBuilder.build());

    mockMvc
            .perform(post("/api/v1.0/movies/{id}/contributions/photos", 1)
                .contentType(...)
                .content(...))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());
}
```

I do not know how to set the correct type for the transmitted data, set the content. Only [tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800726/using-spring-mvc-test-to-unit-test-multipart-post-request) about sending only files (not in objects) are available. But there are no guides where the file is one of the fields in the object. How to do it?

Comment: You are not going to send files via mockmvc aren't you?

Comment: I want to replace it with a method post("/api/v1.0/movies/{id}/contributions/photos", 1), 
and as content, I want to send a contribution object. But I do not know how to do it?

Comment: if you replace the code then you should update the question.