# How to resolve MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException with MockMvc?

Tags: spring-mvc, mockito, multipartform-data, mockmvc

I'm writing a unit test for a controller method that accepts a `MultipartFile`
and a custom object `MessageAttachment`. So far I can see that the MultipartFile is the correct format for the request but the MessageAttachment is not.

The parsing of the `messageAttachment` throws a server side 500 error with `MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException`.

It seem to be an issue with converting the MessageAttachment to a MockMultipartFile in the test. This is similar to the example shown here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21805186

Question:

How can you resolve a MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException with MockMvc?

**Controller method under test**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data", produces = "application/json")
        public ResponseEntity<MessageAttachment> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam(value = "file", required = true) MultipartFile file, @RequestParam(value = "messageAttachment") MessageAttachment messageAttachment) {

            //do stuff with the file and attachment passed in..  
            MessageAttachment attachment = new MessageAttachment();

            return ResponseEntity.accepted().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                    "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "\"").body(attachment);
        }
```

**MockMvc Test**

```
@Test
public void shouldSaveUploadedFile() throws Exception {


        // Given
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        MessageAttachment messageAttachment = new MessageAttachment();  
        messageAttachment.setTimestamp(new Date());

        MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", "test.txt", "text/plain",
                "Spring Framework".getBytes());

        //Mapping the msgAttachment to a MockMultipartFile HERE
        MockMultipartFile msgAttachment = new MockMultipartFile("messageAttachment", "","application/json",
                 mapper.writeValueAsString(messageAttachment).getBytes());

        // When
        this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/media/")
                .file(multipartFile)
                .file(msgAttachment)).andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());

}
```

**Console output of MockMvcResultHandlers.print()**

```
MockHttpServletRequest:                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      HTTP Method = POST                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      Request URI = /media/                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
       Parameters = {}                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
          Headers = {Content-Type=[multipart/form-data]}                                                                                                                                                                                        
             Body = <no character encoding set>                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    Session Attrs = {}                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

Handler:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
             Type = com.fizz.buzz.fizzapi.controller.MediaUploadController                                                                                                                                                             
           Method = public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.fizz.buzz.fizzapi.model.MessageAttachment> com.fizz.buzz.fizzapi.controller.MediaUploadController.handleFileUpload(org.springframework.web.multipart.Mu
ltipartFile,com.fizz.buzz.fizzapi.model.MessageAttachment,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)                                                                                                                                       

Async:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    Async started = false                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
     Async result = null                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

Resolved Exception:                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
             Type = org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException                                                                                                                                     

ModelAndView:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        View name = null                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
             View = null                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            Model = null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `@RequestPart` instead of `@RequestParam` for the part of the request that is `application/json`. The javadoc for `@RequestPart` states

> Supported method argument types include `MultipartFile` in conjunction
>   with Spring's `MultipartResolver` abstraction,
>   `javax.servlet.http.Part` in conjunction with Servlet 3.0 multipart
>   requests, **or otherwise for any other method argument, the content of
>   the part is passed through an `HttpMessageConverter` taking into
>   consideration the 'Content-Type' header of the request part**. This is
>   analogous to what `@RequestBody` does to resolve an argument based on
>   the content of a non-multipart regular request.
>
> Note that `@RequestParam` annotation can also be used to associate the
>   part of a "multipart/form-data" request with a method argument
>   supporting the same method argument types. **The main difference is that
>   when the method argument is not a String, `@RequestParam` relies on type
>   conversion via a registered `Converter` or `PropertyEditor` while
>   `@RequestPart` relies on `HttpMessageConverters` taking into consideration
>   the 'Content-Type' header of the request part.** `@RequestParam` is likely
>   to be used with name-value form fields while `@RequestPart` is likely to
>   be used with parts containing more complex content (e.g. JSON, XML).

Presumably, you haven't registered a `Converter`, nor a `PropertyEditor`, to parse the content of that part, whereas an `HttpMessageConverter` for JSON is automatically registered (depending on your Spring MVC/Boot version) if you have Jackson on the classpath.