# Multipart with format other than CSV not able to find file on classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, multipart

I have file names test.csv ,test.xml ,test.text on my classpath(src/main/resources) folder.

I  am creating Mutlipart for my Junit test case as follows :

```
MultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("test.csv","test.csv","text/csv",
                new FileInputStream(new File("test.csv")));
```

This is working fine.

However when I am trying below code for XMl,it gives FileNotFoundException.

```
MultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("test.xml","test.xml","text/xml",
                    new FileInputStream(new File("test.xml")));
```

Can anyone pls let me know,what can be issue?

Comment: Looks like typo error "tes.xml", use "test.xml"

Comment: Thanks,but typo was here only,not in the code.

Comment: Maybe put them to `src/test/resources/` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got resolution as below :

```
MockMultipartFile   mockitoMultipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("test.xml","test.xml","text/xml",
                this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream("test.xml"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are mocking, you should use like this.

```
MockMultipartFile mockMultipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("test.xml","test.xml","text/xml",
                    new FileInputStream(new File("test.xml")));
```

The actual structure should be like this.

```
MockMultipartFile mockMultipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("test", "test.xml", <XML MEDIA TYPE>,
      "String contents".getBytes()));
```

For more reference, see below the links.
https://www.codota.com/code/java/classes/org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile

[Using Spring MVC Test to unit test multipart POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800726/using-spring-mvc-test-to-unit-test-multipart-post-request)

Comment: Thanks Sambit but it did not help.Still gettin same exception.

Comment: Can you provide the exception stack details ?

Comment: java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<com.test.exception.MyException> but was<java.io.FileNotFoundException>
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:28)
 at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)

Comment: Actually,I dont have String content.I have a file,which needs to be read,so I am using following constructor of MockitoMultipartFile:

Comment: MockMultipartFile(
   String name,String originalFilename,String contentType, InputStream contentStream)